# Showing double orthogonal complement of $X$ is $X$

Tags: functional-analysis

I know this has been asked many times but I know there's a way using the orthogonal projection.

So if we have $H$ a Hilbert and then $X \subset H$ a closed linear subspace, then for any $x \in H$ there are unique $u \in X$ , $v \in X^{\perp } $ such that $x=u+v$.

How can I use this to show that $(X^{\perp })^{\perp } \subset X $?

Answer (score 1):

For any $w \in (X^\perp)^\perp$, we write it as $w = u + v$ with $u \in X$ and $v \in X^\perp$.

Since $w$ is orthogonal to the whole $X^\perp$ and in particular to $v$, we have $$0 = \langle w, v\rangle = \langle u, v\rangle + \langle v, v\rangle = |v|^2$$ because $\langle u, v\rangle = 0$.

This means that $v = 0$ and we have $w = u \in X$.